# Multiple Canvas images appearing randomly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to apply different images to multiple canvas.

The images are passed into a json array that is generated in the code behind and then looped through drawing to there specific canvas.

Now this appears to work on occasion sometimes rendering sometimes not.

So here is the code.

```
function renderPlayer() {
        var imagesList = <%=imageList %>;
        var size = imagesList.length;
        for(var key in imagesList)
        {
            var image = imagesList[key][1];
            var gridPosition = imagesList[key][0];
            var playerCanvas = document.getElementById(gridPosition);
            window.context2 = playerCanvas.getContext("2d");
            //context2.save();
            playerCanvas.setAttribute("width", 97);
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = image;
            context2.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 10, 97, 97);
         }
    }
```

The above code places them where I expect them to but no every time the page is rendered.

However the bellow code appears to only render the last image.

```
        function renderPlayer() {
        var imagesList = <%=imageList %>;
        var size = imagesList.length;
        for(var key in imagesList)
        {
            var image = imagesList[key][1];
            var gridPosition = imagesList[key][0];
            var playerCanvas = document.getElementById(gridPosition);
            window.context2 = playerCanvas.getContext("2d");
            //context2.save();
            playerCanvas.setAttribute("width", 97);
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function(){
            context2.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 10, 97, 97);
            };
            imageObj.src = image;

         }
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions why this may not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same old problem... all of your image `onload` methods refer to one and only `imageObj` that gets overwritten every time through the loop.

```
for(var key in imagesList)
{
    var image = imagesList[key][1];
    var gridPosition = imagesList[key][0];
    var playerCanvas = document.getElementById(gridPosition);
    window.context2 = playerCanvas.getContext("2d");
    //context2.save();
    playerCanvas.setAttribute("width", 97);
    (function(){
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function(){
           context2.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 10, 97, 97);
        };
        imageObj.src = image;
    })();
 }
```

by wrapping in a immediately executing function block, each `imageObj` becomes it's own variable, which each onload function *captures*.

Comment: Thanks for this JayC. The same issue with only one image appearing in the browser still happens however when I step through the code in chrome all 3 images appear as I would expect, just not on a normal run through.

Comment: Is there any reason why we are issuing the exact same `drawImage` command for the three images? Are the drawings supposed to be consecutive but with delays?  I'm missing something here.

Comment: Yeah actually this is the correct answer all that was missing was passing in the variables I need in the immediate executing function. So in my case it was context2 and image that needed to be inside both brackets. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is failing because you need to wait for the image to be loaded before you can draw it in the canvas. The randomness is caused by the fact that sometimes the image will have loaded by the time you run the `context2.drawImage(..)` command and sometimes it won't, by placing this code inside the `onload` handler of the image you should guarantee that the image data is present.

The second example looks better, but you should change `onLoad` to `onload` and move the lines

```
var playerCanvas = document.getElementById(gridPosition);
var context2 = playerCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

outside the `for` loop, also note the change to the second line.

Comment: yeah sorry the second example is actually onload a typo by myself